# is it possible to copy only new files? xcopy/robocopy

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

I created a copy of folder 1 and named it 2

My ERP reads this folder 2 and moves the files to folder 3

I need a command (xcopy / robocopy ...) to copy the new files that arrive in folder 1 to folder 2

*I don't want the ERP to re-read files that are already in folder 3*

Comment: Use `xcopy /D` to copy only files that are newer than their corresponding destination files. If your ERP is erasing the files it processes from folder 3, then you'll need a more complex solution.

Comment: So you meant to *move* the files from 1 to 2.

Comment: I ended up creating the function directly in erp (with 2 arrays, FOR, IF / ELSE)

scroll through the files in folder 1, and if you don't have folder 3, copy to folder 2